# Is there an efficient way to search variable parameters in mySQL with different results?

Tags: php, mysql, categories

I have quite a complex question and due to the specifications I've had no luck finding any help with this. Scratching my head for a few months.

I have multiple parameters however in this question I'll focus on only 3

- Category ($cat)
- Subcategory ($sub)
- Genre ($gen)

MySQL columns:

```
id | category | subcategory | genre | account | date_received | date_modified
```

(Account is assigned: 1-3)

I would like the results to return:

- if only Category is offered:
  first the row `account = 1`, then `date_received`, followed by `date_modified` (give no preference to accounts `2 & 3`)
- if only Category AND Subcategory is offered:
  first the row `account = 1` and `account = 2`, then `date_received`, followed by `date_modified` (give no preference to account `3`)
- if only Category AND Subcategory AND genre is offered:
  first the row `account = 1` and `account = 2` and `account = 3`, then `date_received`, followed by `date_modified`

So far I have this:

```
if ($cat AND empty($sub) AND empty($gen)) {
    $run = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM db 
                        WHERE (category='$cat') 
                        ORDER BY case when account = '1'  then 1 else 2 end,    
                            GREATEST(date_received, modified_date, account) DESC ");
} else if ($cat AND $sub AND empty($gen)) {
    $run = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM db 
                        WHERE (category='$cat' AND subcategory='$sub') 
                        ORDER BY case when account = '2'  then 1 else 2 end,
                            GREATEST(date_received, modified_date, account) DESC 
                      ");
} else if ($cat AND $sub AND $gen) { 
    $run = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM db 
                        WHERE (category='$cat' AND subcategory='$sub' AND genre='$gen') 
                        ORDER BY case when account = '3'  then 1 else 2 end, 
                            GREATEST(date_received, modified_date, account) DESC 
                        "); }
```

Is there an efficient way of combing these and echoing the different results?
It feels really messy.

Many thanks everyone for any tips you can offer.

Comment: Should there be a `LIMIT` clause in the first query, like the other two?

Comment: Sorry the limit should have been removed for the purpose of the question, each query is used with the same infinite ajax scroll.

Comment: what happens if no conditions are passed?

Comment: I assume `genre = '$sub'` should be `genre = '$gen'`.

Comment: Yes that was a typo here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the conditions in an array, and the preferred account in a variable.

```
$conds = array();
if ($cat) {
    $account = 1;
    $conds[] = "category = '$cat'";
}
if ($sub) {
    $account = 2;
    $conds[] = "subcategory = '$sub'";
}
if ($gen) {
    $account = 3;
    $conds[] = "genre = '$gen'";
}
if (!empty($conds)) {
    $cond_str = implode(' AND ', $conds);
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM db
            WHERE $cond_str
            ORDER BY IF(account = $account, 1, 2),
                GREATEST(date_received, modified_date, account) DESC";
    $run = mysql_query($sql);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, many thanks for the quick reply.
Working beautifully.